# conditional statement seems to be storing multiple values for the same variable.. scoping error?

Tags: jquery, scope

I have a click event handler with jquery.
if a text field is blank i return false else submit some variables to another function. if i fire the event again it appears that the previous variables are still set and new ones are set with the function cycling twice. I hope that makes since as i don't quite understand what is happening.

the clickable:

```
<p class="field_select custom" data-table="" data-field="_text">Your Custom Text</p>
```

The handler:

```
$('.field_select').click(function(){

    if ($(this).hasClass('custom')){
        //This is a custom field

        //reset the input to empty
        $('#custom_text_input').val('');

        //get the data we need for our ajax function
        field = $(this).data('field');
        table = $(this).data('table');

       //open up the dialog with the input field
       $('#custom_field_div').dialog({
           modal: true,
           width: 500,
           height: 275,
           buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
       });

       //when we close the dialog check for empty value and fire function
        $('#custom_field_div').on('dialogclose', function(){
            name = $('#custom_text_input').val();
            if (name !== ''){
                //the user filled the field - fire the function.
                custom = $('#custom_text_input').val();
                append_field(field, name, custom, table);
            }
            else {
                //the user did not fill the field, do nothing.
                alert('not recording anything');
                alert(name);
                return false;

//------------------after the first blank submission the second will 
//------throw the alerts twice!!! and then the next time THREE and so on... 
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                //this is not a custom field
               table = $(this).data('table');
               field = $(this).data('field');
               name = $(this).html();
               append_field(field, name, table);
            }
        });
```

The HTML for the hidden dialog div

```
<div id="custom_field_div">
    <label>Enter your custom text...</label>
    <input type="text" id="custom_text_input" maxlength="255" rows="3" style="width: 100%!important; height: 50px;"></textarea>
</div>
```

I am not seeing any errors in the console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the click handler runs, this line is executed:

```
$('#custom_field_div').on('dialogclose', function(){
```

Which adds **another** handler for the `dialogclose` event. When that event happens, all the handlers are triggered.

Refactor your code to set up the dialog outside of the click handler, or destroy the dialog every time it closes. I would suggest the first option.

Comment: so i have the two selectors that get information from $(this) which is the original clicked element. Would you store those two values in hidden inputs or would you create a javascript object for those?

Comment: Instead of binding to the dialogclose event, could you just put that logic in the "OK" button click function?

Comment: The only good reason to use hidden inputs is if it's part of a form being submitted.

Comment: @jason I suppose i could.

Comment: @barmar, you would rather set a global then for the "dialogclose" function to access?